# link between ID field and a description field in a table using Object data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using ASP.NET with C#

I'm using a drop down list that takes the description of each row from a table named `COLOR` containing 2 columns: `ID` and `Description(the name of the color).`

I am using object data source, so how do I make a link so that the Color appears by description and not by ID in the drop down list and in my grid view?

P.S.: In my object data source, I'm using the function `GetColorByColorID`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the select statement for your dropdown list should be:

```
"select Description from COLOR"
```

and for the gridview shoud be:

```
"select * from COLOR where DESCRIPTION="+dropdownList.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Comment: or dropdownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

Comment: this can't work because if you are using the object data source u can't write an SQL command.

Comment: If you use Object Data Source, then make use of: the filtering parameters available with the data soruce like: Control Parameters, Session Parameter/ QueryString Parameter etc.. Control Parameters suits this case..